# Display current post position in Elementor Posts widget

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, widgets

I'm using Elementor 2.6.8 + Elementor Pro 2.6.2

I'm designing an Archive template to display a list of Custom Post Types filtered by custom taxonomy terms.
I'm using Posts Widget from Elementor Pro to do this without a line of code.

Also, thanks to Ele Custom Skin plugin (1.2.0), I can design each post skin in a custom way (hopefully Elementor Pro will provide this in the future)/

Now, I want to display, in each post, the post's current position in the list (=in the WP loop).

I tried with this code snippet that I added to each post with the ShortCode Widget.

```php
add_shortcode( 'current_post_count', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    $out = $wp_query->current_post;
    return $out;
} );
```

But this always return -1.

I suppose the reason is that, in the context of the Posts Widget, the global $wp_query is not the one to get the info from. I suppose the widget use another variable.
But thenm I don't know how to achieve this. Maybe if I could get the actual $query variable in use ? Or maybe use the Query ID parameter offered by the Posts Widget?

I don't know how to get this to work.

Anything to point me towards the right direction guys? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by using a more recent version (1.1.1) of Elementor Custom Skin Pro plugin, which allows to use dynamic values directly in the template content, that are interpreted during the Loop.
In my case, {{index}} does the trick.

Comment: I have the same issue where did you enter {{index}}?